# Grab element from html frame with session in cookie

Tags: session, curl, element

I am trying to grab element from website:

```
https://esterownik.pl/device/21283
```

Element is inside div class 'value'. Parent is:
class="ttip scada_reg screen_item editable" with id="0|next_fuel_time" and data-title="Data kolejnego zasypu">

I noticed that website generates cookie with PHPSESSID for example:
cfaa4q7o9vpxc0dcovrnd08nh7 for another domain `cs1.esterownik.pl`

[image: this element should be scrapped]

I've tried with python and other stuff with no luck. Curl is finishing with status NO_SESSION by my command:

```
curl -X POST -d "name=pub_hash&id=pub_hash&value=9e3bb3aa3a24d021bf89ae05719338117000836a4f193f677f0682aa84e6ee70" "https://cs1.esterownik.pl/index.php?id=21283"
```

How can I grab this datatime value?

Answer (score 0):

ok, done with Selenium project:

```
driver.get("https://esterownik.pl/device/xxxxx")
driver.switch_to.frame('device_iframe')
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="0|next_fuel_time"]/div/span')[0].text
print(driver.page_source)
```